# UIWebView Can't Scroll Once Keyboard Hides

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have an iPad app that has a UIWebView containing several text inputs. I have the web view set to only scroll vertically. When I click on a text input and show and hide the keyboard -- I can no longer scroll up and down. I can tap on more inputs, but I can't scroll.

It's strange because when I tap on an input, I'm able to scroll up and down with the keyboard being shown. But, as soon as I hide the keyboard, I can no longer scroll.

I'm currently using NSNotification center to capture the event that happens when the keyboard is hidden, but I'm not sure what needs to happen. I've tried re-enabling scrolling or resigning the first responder back to the web view or to the web view's scrollview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardHidden) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

-(void)keyboardHidden
{
    // Does something need to happen in here??
}
```

Comment: you made the webview first responder after the keyboard gets hidden? [yourWebView becomeFirstResponder]?

Comment: Yes, still was unable to scroll

Comment: Why won't you use Javascript for hiding the keyboard?
jQuery: $('input[type=text]').blur();